# uikit downloaded css isn't functional

Tags: css, uikit

I'm using CDNJS to access the uikit library. The CSS I download from their customizer, which allows you to create your own personal theme scheme, isn't functional. Below is how I linked to my CSS files, the path is correct because my portfolioStyle.css file is functional.

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Contact</title>


<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/portfolioStyle.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/uikit.css">

<!-- UIkit -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.27.5/css/uikit.min.css" />

<!-- Google Fonts -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Caveat|Stoke" rel="stylesheet">
```